# ndk-stack xamarin Fatal signal 11

Tags: xamarin, ndk-stack

My app is closing when do certain action, I use adb logcat to get the log trace, searching out I found this, 
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 27798.....
I'm trying to use ndk-stack to know about the error but I have no idea how to use it with xamarin

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/xamarin

Comment: I'm alredy using app center but native crashes are not logged, I just ned to know how to use ndk-stack but I cannot make it work

Comment: @user3525706 Have you symbolized the crash?

Comment: symbolized how??